# Detect Reaction on discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making a discord bot, and I have a problem with a waifu command.
With this command the bot sends an embed, and I want to detect when someone reacts to this embed. I tried this code but nothing happens.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const axios = require("axios")
const Client = new Discord.Client;

module.exports = {
    name : 'waifu',
    description : "waifu command",
    execute(message, args) {


        Client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
            message.channel.send("Reacted")
        })

        axios.get("https://api.waifu.pics/sfw/waifu")
        .then((res) => {


            let wembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`Voici votre waifu ${message.author.username}`)
                .setImage(res.data.url)
            message.channel.send(wembed)
            .then(function (message) {
                message.react("❤")
                Client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
                    console.log("reacted")
                })

              })


        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error("ERR: ", err)
        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) listener inside your `message` listener. You can however set up a reaction collector using [`createReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) for example, like in my example below:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const axios = require('axios')

module.exports = {
  name: 'waifu',
  description: 'waifu command',
  execute(message, args) {
    axios
      .get('https://api.waifu.pics/sfw/waifu')
      .then((res) => {
        let wembed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(`Voici votre waifu ${message.author.username}`)
          .setImage(res.data.url);

        // make sure you use a different var name here
        // like msg instead of message
        message.channel.send(wembed).then((msg) => {
          msg.react('❤');

          // set up a filter to only collect reactions with the ❤ emoji
          let filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '❤';
          let collector = msg.createReactionCollector(filter);

          collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
            // in case you want to do something when someone reacts with ❤
            console.log('reaction added');
          });

          collector.on('remove', (reaction, user) => {
            // in case you want to do something when someone removes their reaction
            console.log('reaction removed');
          });
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('ERR: ', err);
      });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things here.

First, you defined `message` twice; once as the message initiating the command that originated from your command handler, and once as the message the bot sent.  You need to rename one of these or else various unexpected issues may arise.

Second, you should never define your client twice.  Instead, you should reuse the client.  To do this, you can either export it to your command handler the same way you export `message` and `args`, or you can access it via `<message>.client` and use it the same way you did here.